# Do two equivalent metrics always generate same $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I'm self studying probability theory and I read in Billingsley's "Convergence of Probability Measures" that if two metrics are equivalent, then they generate the same $\sigma$-algebra. (In fact he then asks to prove as an exercises that inequivalent metrics can generate same Borel sets, result which I found surprising in a certain sense!!). I don't seem do find the proof for this anywhere, however. Where can I find such proof? Or is it a simple result to prove?

Comment: Yes equivalent metrics generate the same open sets hence the same Borel sets.

Comment: @Momo: I did not downvote this question or vote to close it, but I think that likening people who think MSE questions should be backed up by relevant references to [Nazis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazism) is a little over the top.

Comment: @Kavi: is there a good reference where I can read this proof?

Comment: @Momo: thanks for the tip. Already edited the question :)

Comment: Can you state the definition of how a metric "generates" a $\sigma$-algebra? And what it means for two metrics to be "equivalent"?

Comment: @RobArthan Haha, I was referring to [these](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammar_Nazi) Nazis, not the real ones.

Comment: @Momo: OK. Perhaps "QA thought police" would be a better way to put it. *1984* is a happier source than *Mein Kampf*.

Comment: @Troposphere Two metrics are equivalent on a space $X$ if they induce the same metric topology on $X$. You can verify if they're equivalent it by showing that every sequence that converge in $X$ with respect to one metric converges as well in respect to the other.

Comment: @RobArthan Yeah, didn't mean to hit a nerve, sorry.

Comment: @YetAnotherUsr Ok, so if the topology is the same and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is by definition the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology, what this tells you?

Comment: @Momo thank you!! ;)